# PHP Cookie not Initializing

Tags: php

I am wanting to store an array in a cookie, the below works only when the script has been executed once (the cookies are in the users browser). The first time you execute the script the below error is received (the cookies are being stored), execute a second, third etc. time the script has no issues. Any ideas as to why this is occurring, is an initialization of the cookie values required.

```
The below errors are displayed 3 times within the while loop.
Notice: Undefined index: cookievalue1 in C:\domain\cookies.php
Notice: Undefined index: cookievalue2 in C:\domain\cookies.php
Notice: Undefined index: cookievalue3 in C:\domain\cookies.php



<?PHP

$i = 1;
$x = 4;

$username = "Username";
$orderno = "12345678";
$item1 = "Firstitem";
$price1 = "$50";
$item2 = "Seconditem";
$price2 = "$46";
$subtotal = "$96";
$tax = "5%";
$total = "$100";
$var = NULL;

$cookiearray = array($username,$orderno,$item1,$price1,$item2,$price2,$subtotal,$tax,$total);      
print_r($cookiearray);


while ($i < $x) {   

    $cookiearray1 = serialize($cookiearray);
    setcookie("cookievalue" . $i, $cookiearray1, time()+3600);
    print "printing cookie  "; $cook1 = $_COOKIE['cookievalue'.$i];
    print $cook1; print '<br></br>';print '<br></br>';

    $var = unserialize($cookiearray1);

    print "printing var"; print $var[1];
    print '<br></br>';print '<br></br>';

    $var2 = unserialize($cook1);
    print $var2[$i];
    print '<br></br>';print '<br></br>';

   $i = $i + 1;


}



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

then [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) explains this clearly:

> Common Pitfalls:
>
> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

Comment: Thanks :) I will run the script and reload the page